# Is there an appender/configuration for log4j or Logback that allows you to write to a GZIP file?

Tags: log4j, gzip, logback

I'm having issue with logging that is using up too much DiskIO and too much space when a large number of users are using a live system which has issues which only happen in live.

Is there a log4j or (preferably) LogBack appender/configuration that will allow writing directly to a GZIP compressed file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This feature already exists in Logback. Take a look at [appenders](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html) section, specifically at [time based rolling policy](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#TimeBasedRollingPolicy).

Quote:

Just like `FixedWindowRollingPolicy`, `TimeBasedRollingPolicy` supports automatic file compression. This feature is enabled if the value of the `fileNamePattern` option ends with `.gz` or `.zip`.

Also take a look at [time and size based rolling policy](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP).

You can setup rollover to occur after one log file hits a certain limit.

I don't believe writing directly to a GZIP compressed file for every log statement would be feasable, since this would create a pretty big performance overhead. Using a combination of existing features sounds reasonable to me.

Answer (score 1):

The space issue is already solved by logback. It will compress your log files during rollover. The IO issue is quite a different one and I am afraid logback does not offer a solution.